# Lubuntu Install on Dell Inspiron 6000

Tags: lubuntu, dell

I am having trouble installing Lubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Inspiron 6000 laptop with a scrubbed-clean HD and 2 GB of RAM. I downloaded the OS on a Windows 7 machine and transferred it to a 4 GB thumb drive and tried it on the laptop. It came up *no bootable media*. I then went back to the PC and unpacked the download on the thumb drive. Same answer. What do I do now? Please understand--I am not a techie! Also--there is *no operating system* on the Dell I. 6000 so I cannot instruct anything from it. I have found instructions for resetting the BIOS on this computer to be very confusing

Comment: You have to install the download on your thumb drive; you can not just copy it to it.

Comment: How do I Install the down load on the thumb drive?

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple tool call Etcher which will make loading a .iso file onto the USB and have it boot into Lubuntu installer very easy.

You can find instructions on the site for using the tool, here's a briefer:

- Get the .iso file from [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.net/downloads/)
- Install Etcher [here](https://etcher.io/)
- Plug USB in computer and open Etcher
- Select the .iso as the image to flash
- Press Flash

The flashing process takes a bit of time, though Lubuntu is a rather compact OS.

From what I've gathered, the Dell laptops allow you to boot to a USB drive by pressing F12 on boot.

Once booted, the installer should launch.